# Sort NSMutableArray according to object

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am getting JSON like below:

```
"Array1": 
[
  {
    "abc": "3_name",
    "id": 34,
    "order": [3]
  },
  {
    "abc": "1_name",
    "id": 50,
    "order": [1]
  },
  {
    "abc": "2_name",
    "id": 4,
    "order": [2]
  }
]
```

I don't know how to sort the Array1 according to "order" which is itself an array. Please help. I could not figure out how to sort it using NSSortDescriptor or any other method available in Objective-C.

Comment: Update your question with your attempts to sort this array.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Did you get it to work using my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'de want to sort using a comparator, which would look something like:

```
id customCompare = ^(NSMutableDictionary * obj1, NSMutableDictionary * obj2) {
    return [obj1[@"order"][0] compare:obj2[@"order"][0]];
};

NSArray *sortedArray = [jsonData[@"Array1"] sortedArrayUsingComparator:customCompare];
```

Where jsonData should be replaced by the correct name of the dict holding the Array1.

Comment: You neglected to mention that this `compare:` method needs to exist for the objects in `array1`, not in the class calling `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`. And this doesn't take into account that you are sorting an array of dictionaries and the sort order is on a further array in those dictionaries.

Comment: @maddy changed to local comparator for clarity

Comment: It's still completely wrong. `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` doesn't take a block as an argument. And the implementation of the block doesn't reflect the data being sorted.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, nice catch. Updated the example to exactly match question data.